# How to add a delimiter in twig to a string?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i have time in format HHMM as string and would like to add " : " after hours. is there a simple filter to split string after two characters and add a delimiter?

Answer (score 3):

You can split by position like this

```
 {% set bar = "aabbcc"|split('', 2) %}
 {# bar contains ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'] #}
```

As described in the [doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html#arguments)

So you can do something like:

```
{% set bar = "1203"|split('', 2) %}
{# bar contains ['12', '03'] #}
```

now let's do:

```
{{ bar[0]~":"~bar[1] }}
```

this will output:

```
12:03
```

Better if you build a `macro` or a `TWIG extension` with the function

Hope this help

Comment: @user3826926 if the answer fulfill your requirements please accept the solution. thanks